# Refresh dispatch model without losing entity mapping

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm understanding the concepts of BOT Framework by following [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/virtual-assistant/tutorials/customize-assistant/csharp/4-edit-your-cognitive-models/).

*Step 1:*
Followed steps to create new KB and then cognitiveModels.json is updated with new values 
and `.\Deployment\Scripts\update_cognitive_models.ps1 -RemoteToLocal` command need to be 
executed which will update Dispatch model.

*Step 2:* 
For make BOT more user friendly, added few `entities` and mapped to `Intents`. Till here everything works fine.

*Step 3:*
Repeated step 1 then `entities` which were mapped earlier are wipped off.

**Question 1:** How to refresh Dispatch model without losing mapped entities?

**Question 2:** How to update Entities using json for the existing LUIS model?

Please clarify or point me to right resource.

Comment: your issue is being investigated in GitHub. Adding the link here so that others can refer to as well https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/1432

Comment: @ranusharao - since no one picked up here to answer, I posted same question in github.

Answer (score 0):

Here is suggestion which I received from Product Group Team.

A user already has one or more LUIS, QnA Maker apps/models, or even some flat files of intent-utterances and the user would like to create a meta-app to dispatch bot traffics to those child apps. In this scenario, entities should be (manually) added to the child LUIS apps instead of to the Dispatch parent app, so that the entity definitions won't get wiped out after the Dispatch app/model is refreshed.

A user has a LUIS app and he/she can use Dispatch to evaluate the app's intent prediction performance in a 5-fold cross validation process.
As you can see from the scenarios, Dispatch focuses on intent prediction/dispatching and evaluation, so that entity definitions are not persisted. Please maintain your entities in the child apps, not at the Dispatch level.